# Adding div according to cm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can the width and size of the added new divs be set in cm?

e.g. width:10cm; the value that appears on each computer changes and it does not exactly match when measured with a ruler. I guess because of the resolution.

I want to reach the same result by measuring the div on the screen with the ruler.

How can I do this calculation?

Comment: To achieve this you would need to know the DPI setting of the client machine, which JS cannot get access to. Why do you need this?

Comment: I want to create a label. The output on the paper should be according to the actual cm. I need to arrange it on the computer before I get it.

Comment: So it's the print size that should be accurate not the screen size? Doesn't `width:10cm` give accurate print size?

Comment: Sites like iruler.net has done it. You just need to know/guess some specs of your clients monitor. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Comment: You should check this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/

Comment: No, the print size varies according to the label type.